# How to get the feedback in Github from Jenkins server?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, junit

I'm building unit test in python with Github and Jenkins server.

I build a freestyle project in Jenkins and add the following shell in Build shell

```
python tests/run.py
```

I wonder how to return the results of unit test in Jenkins server to Github?
For example, the terminal output of one build is like

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest
The recommended git tool is: NONE
...
[JenkinsTest] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins4582176743994375625.sh
+ python tests/run.py
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_dir (test_dir.MFTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/tests/test_dir.py", line 10, in test_dir
    self.assertTrue(os.path.exists('tests/test_abc.py'))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
Testing MFTest.test_dir
...
```

Comment: what do you mean by sent to github? why don't you use github actions if you want data in github?

Comment: @deadshot Because GitHub actions provide only limited memory resource(7GB). Besides, sending to GitHub means: when the unit test failed, I hope the Jenkins server returns the terminal output to GitHub, so that the contributor in Github can know why it failed.

Comment: still don't understand how the contributor will know how are you planing to send the details?